# How do I search for an exact 'tag' word in a file using Windows 8.1 search?

Tags: windows-8, search, windows-8.1

I want to tag my text documents, using tags such as @done, or @inprogress.

When I use Windows 8.1 search for @done, I get any document that contains the word 'done', regardless of the @ sign. This won't work for me: I only want it to match documents that contain the tag including the @ sign.

I have tried using double quotation marks "@done", single quotation marks 'done', but this has no effect. Windows ignores the @ sign.

If this won't work, can anyone recommend a good way to tag plain text documents so that they are searchable in Windows? It would be ideal if it was actually OS-agnostic, so that the same tags are searchable in Linux, OSX, and even iOS and Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that you can tag pictures, word documents and others. But tag text files to make them searchable in Windows 8.1 is not possible.

## Add tags or other properties to a file

*Applies to Windows Vista
File properties display information about your files, such as the name of the author and the date that the file was last modified. Although there are many properties associated with your files, tags are often the most useful, because you can add tags to your files that contain words or phrases that make the files easier to find.
You can organize and find files quickly when you search and filter using file properties. For example, you can quickly narrow the view of files in the Documents folder to just those files written by a particular author or those that contain certain tags. But first, you need to add these properties to your files.*

> **Note** 
>   You cannot add or modify the file properties of some types of files.
>   For example, you can add or modify the properties of Microsoft Office
>   documents and Searches, but you can't add or modify the properties of
>   **TXT** or RTF files.

Click [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/add-tags-or-other-properties-to-a-file) for more information.

Comment: Thank you for getting this information. What I'm looking for is a system for tagging every kind of file in a way that is OS-agnostic. Maybe in five years I'll be using a Mac, or Linux, I don't know, but I won't want to have to re-tag everything before making a change. I know that tagging text files is possible, I just need to find a way of making it efficient. I could for example start every tag with a numeric code, instead of the @ sign. So I could use 1583729done (instead of @done), and I would use Windows to search for this. But it's not efficient.

Comment: I think tags only work for files that are easily accessible, I can only access tagged files that are on desktop and tagged in search options. Also they come in the Files menu.